# Matlab: reverse of eps? Accuracy on positive weight?

Tags: matlab, noise, eps, computation

eps returns the distance from 1.0 to the next largest double-precision number, so I can use it to interpret the numbers value on negative weight position. But for very large number with value on high positive weight position, what can I use to interpret?

I mean that I need to have some reference to count out computation noise on numbers obtained on Matlab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)?

It discusses rounding error (what you're calling "computation noise"), the IEEE 754 standard for representation of floating-point numbers, and implementations of floating-point math on computers.

I believe that reading this paper would answer your question, or at least give you more insight into exactly how floating point math works.

---

Some clarifications to aid your understanding - too big to fit in the comments of @Richante's post:

Firstly, the difference between `realmin` and `eps`:

- `realmin` is the smallest *normalised* floating point number. You can represent smaller numbers in denormalised form.
- `eps` is the smallest increment between distinct numbers. `realmin` = `eps(realmin) * 2^52`.

"Normalised" and "denormalised" floating point numbers are explained in the paper linked above.

Secondly, rounding error is no indicator of how much you can "trust" the `n`th digit of a number.

Take, for example, this:

```
>> ((0.1+0.1+0.1)^512)/(0.3^512)

ans =

    1.0000
```

We're dividing `0.3^512` by itself, so the answer should be exactly one, right? We should be able to trust every digit up to `eps(1)`.

The error in this calculation is actually `400 * eps`:

```
>> ((0.1+0.1+0.1)^512)/(0.3^512) - 1

ans =

  9.4591e-014

>> ans / eps(1)

ans =

   426
```

The **calculation** error, i.e. the extent to which the `n`th digit is untrustworthy, is far greater than `eps`, the floating-point roundoff error in the representation of the answer. Note that we only did six floating-point operations here! You can easily rack up millions of FLOPs to produce one result.

I'll say it one more time: `eps()` is *not an indicator of the error in your calculation*. Do not attempt to display : "My result is 1234.567 +/- eps(1234.567)". That is meaningless and deceptive, because it implies your numbers are more precise than they actually are.

`eps`, the rounding error in the *representation* of your answer, is only 1 part per billion trillion or so. Your real enemy is the error that accumulates every time you do a floating point operation, and that is what you need to track for a meaningful estimate of the error.

Comment: So, the calculation error define if i can or can't trust on the value of a digit in a particular weight position and not the rounding error. Right? is this that i mistake?

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you're dealing with simulation data, like from a finite element simulation, that already carries an error because finite element modelling is not a perfect model of reality. That error will be far larger than your floating point calculation error and your rounding error combined. (And if you work with real-world data, the error may be as high as 10%!)

Comment: To precise i will not display the result +/- eps(result), i will just display in a separated box of my gui the value of eps, my supervisor  asked me to do that in order to let the user know about how the result in the gui can be trust....What can I say to him?

Comment: Tell him that usually, floating point roundoff error isn't significant enough to worry about. Other sources of error will eat you alive.

Answer (score 2):

Easier to digest than the paper Li-aung Yip recommends would be the Wikipedia article on [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).  Then read *What Every Computer Scientist ...*

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very well worded, but I think you want something that gives the distance from a number to the next smallest double-precision number? If this is the case, then you can just use:

```
x = 100;
x + eps(x)  %Next largest double-precision number
x - eps(-x) %Next smallest double-precision number
```

[Double-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers have a single sign bit, so counting up from a negative number is the same as counting down from a positive.

Edit:
According to `help eps`, "For all X, EPS(X) is equal to EPS(ABS(X))." which really confuses me; I can't see how that can be consistent with double having a single sign bit, and values not being equally spaced.

Comment: Yes, i know my question isn't clear at all. I need to know if in matlab i get number like 2.3234e25 i can "trust" on the value at weight position 10^21: digit 4, or i have to assume that digit is probably affected by computation noise.

Comment: Then I think my example should work for you: `x = 2.3234e25; minimum = x - eps(-x); maximum = x + eps(x);` This will tell you that x is between minimum and maximum (i.e. in this case you can trust the 4 because minimum and maximum both start 2.3234).

Comment: So, i have to use always eps to evaluate the number both when it has digit on negative weight position and when it has digit on positive weight position? Was i wrong to think that eps could be a inferior limit to refer the validity of digits on negative weight position and to think that maybe there would be a corresponding superior limit to refer the validity of digits on positive weight position?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're worried about rounding error? If you're trying to minimise it, do that by performing as few FLOPS as possible and normalising your numbers so that most of them are near 1.

Comment: I implemented a gui for my thesis in which there are some calculation & i insert the value eps just printed on. My work is pioneer & so in this phase in the calculation i didn't used the value eps and so i just let know the user of the gui know the accuracy of that gui implemented in matlab.  Students who will continue my work will do that. My supervisor, who don't has hands on matlab & don't know how it works more than me, asked me the question mentioned above. If there is a "superior limit reference" to print on a box on my gui, to come with the "inferior limit reference" which is the eps.

Comment: So if you wanted to display error bounds like 'x +/- 0.0001' then you could do this. However, as the paper @Li-aungYip linked says, errors can get introduced during calculations - so just displaying the rounding error on the final number is not sufficient. For example, if you do `1 + 1e99 - 1e99` the result is 0. eps(0) will tell you that the rounding error on 0 is 4.9e-324, but actually the result is wrong by 1 - because the rounding error on `1 + 1e99` was much bigger (1.2e83).

Comment: The potential error in a floating point calculation is **far** more than `eps`. Consider `(10^20 + 10) - 10^20 == 10` ... or does it? (On my machine, running Octave, the above expression evaluates to *exactly zero*. That's a lot more error than `eps`.)

Comment: The above is an extreme example (though it does happen with near-singular problems.) More likely is the accumulation of floating point error over multiple calculations - remember the individual error of each calculation you perform builds up on the error from the previous calculation.

Comment: In conclusion i need to display just eps to let user know about the rounding error and it has rule to interpret both number with positive weight position and number with negative weight position. So the answer to my supervisor is that there is just a reference that i have to use both for large number and small number. (my supervisor confused me!). Beside, I have to be conscious that eps is just the rounding on the final number and with printing "eps(double)" that I don't take error computation account. Right?

Comment: Beside, i have another question about. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/304500 this confused me more :(. Can i still stay on my way using eps to print?

Comment: No. `eps` is not a measure of the floating point error in a calculated value. It is a measure of the roundoff error for the last calculation. You can print `eps` if you want, but it's meaningless.

Comment: Ok i get that eps isn't correlated with the computational error, but it is the rounding error ?which define if i can or can't trust on the value of a digit in a particular weight position? Furthermore, why in the discussion mentioned they distinguish eps and realmin?